# How can I remove 'no-cache="Set-Cookie"' when I add a cookie to a HttpResponse?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, cookies

I'm currently returning a cookie from a web service with code like this:

```
HttpResponse response = ...;
var cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName)
{
    Value = cookieValue,
    Expires = expiresDate,
    HttpOnly = true,
    Path = "/",
    Secure = true,
};
response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

This results in the automatic addition of a **no-cache** directive in my Cache-Control header:

> Cache-Control: public, **no-cache="Set-Cookie"**, must-revalidate, max-age=60

My client happens to handle this directive by straight up not caching the response at all.  If I manually remove the **no-cache** directive before it hits the client, caching works great.

How can I prevent .NET from automatically adding this directive to responses containing cookies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HttpResponse` determines whether it should add this directive based on whether the `Cookies` collection is non-empty.  Therefore, if you add the header manually you can hide its presence from .NET:

```
response.AddHeader("Set-Cookie", String.Format(
        "{0}={1}; expires={2}; path=/; secure; HttpOnly",
        cookieName, cookieValue, expiresDate.ToString("R")));
```