# ASP.NET Web API CacheControl

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-headers, cache-control

I am trying to implement CacheControl headers from within a ASP.NET Web Api action ( I realise I can do this using other libraries, and in filters/handlers, but want to do some testing first).

I am following a trivial example from a book that looks like:

```cs
var response = Request.CreateResponse<IEnumerable<string>>(HttpStatusCode.OK,emails);

response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue();
response.Headers.CacheControl.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
response.Headers.CacheControl.MustRevalidate = false;
response.Headers.CacheControl.Public = true;

return response;
```

This code is almost identical to a number of other answers provided on stackoverflow.

However, the web api is not setting cache control header at all! Any ideas?????

When I look at the response in fiddler it looks like the following, as you can the cache-control is set to no-cache.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-MiniProfiler-Ids: ["b7bfde10-e8d3-455d-b40d-2f33eb285023"]
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 25 May 2013 11:54:35 GMT
Content-Length: 24
```

I have tried changing the maxage, mustrevalidate and public values all to no avail...

Comment: I just check your response code... working for me. It seems that the issue is elsewhere...in your solution *(some AOP filter?, attribute?)*

Comment: I agree with Radim, your code is fine.  Do you have any MessageHandlers installed?

Comment: Did you ever find the reason for this not working? I am running into the same issue trying to integrate webapi into a legacy MVC project.

Comment: I have the same issue, using [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] header on the API action. Wonder if this could cause the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Check your request pipeline to see if you have something that is manipulating your response via the `System.Web.HttpResponse` object (ex: `HttpContext.Current.Response`). I've run into cases where adding http cookies via `System.Web.HttpResponse` will wipe out any cache-control headers defined within Web API's `System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage`.

Try avoiding `System.Web.HttpResponse`. If that's not possible, [one workaround as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005279/how-can-i-remove-no-cache-set-cookie-when-i-add-a-cookie-to-a-httpresponse) would be to manually set the cookie header via `AddHeader()` and avoid the `Cookies` collection altogether.