# What is setting no-cache="Set-Cookie"

Tags: cache-control, httpcontext

I'm trying to get my header rounder Caching.  I have the following code in vb.net:

```
With HttpContext.Current.Response 
   .Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public)
   .Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches)
   .Cache.SetLastModified(Now)
   .Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(120))
   .Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120))
End With
```

Which returns the following headers:

```
Cache-Control: public, no-cache="Set-Cookie", must-revalidate, max-age=120
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Expires: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:54:36 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:52:36 GMT
```

But I'm trying to figure out what is setting `no-cache="Set-Cookie"` and how can I switch that on or off?

Comment: [This StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14005279/4072843) looks relevant, and may help.

Answer (score 5):

The no-cache="Set-Cookie" tells the browser not to cache the server "Set-Cookie" header, but follow different rules for the rest of the request.
Here's a discussion from W3C
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Issues/cache-private.html

> In http 1.1, Roy has proposed some features for the new cache-control
>     directive that allow servers to selectively disable caching on
>     specific headers.  This would be, for example:
>      cache-control: no-cache="set-cookie"

Comment: The way I understood that document you linked is that if the "Set-Cookie" header is present then the entire response is not cached. Would be good to get clarification on that and also browser support.